# Multiple left join with same columns

Tags: sas

I have 3 Data sets `A,B,C` which contains the following variables

```
A:

period  region   city 

B:

period  city   Sales

C:

period   region   Sales
```

My goal is to do a left join on `A` using `B` and `C` to get the Sales information based on the geographic location. I tried to in the sequence of steps:

```
/* Left joining B to A based on period and region */

proc sql;

Create table merge1 as

select l.* , r.* from 

A as l left join B as r 

on l.period = r.period and l.city=r.city;

quit;


/* Renaming Sales variable*/

data merged2;

set merge1;

rename Sales= s1;

run;



/*Doing another left join again, this time using C*/


proc sql;

create table merge3 as

select l.*,r.* from

A as l left join C as r

on l.period= r.period and l.region=r.region;

quit;

/*Replacing some of the values*/

data merge4;

set merge3;

Sales1= IFN(s1=., Sales, s1);

drop s1 Sales;

run;
```

My question would be if there are much better/ efficient ways to go about this? Especially on the multiple left joins since the process will get really tedious as the number of datasets and varaibles to be matched increases, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in a single SQL procedure. Since you have multiple tables, you will have to join them one by one.

```
proc sql;
Create table merge1 as select 
    A.* , 
    B.sales as s1,
    C.sales as s2,
    coalesce(B.sales, C.sales) as Sales /*takes first non missing value*/
from A 
    left join B on (A.period = B.period and A.city = B.city)
    left join C on (A.period = C.period and A.region = C.region);
quit;
```